# Chromium (3945.79) page load delay (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, chromium

[image]I have noticed the past week that Chromium (3945.79) now appears to be laggy and slow loading URL content and pages, it hangs and if left takes about 1 minute to actually fulfil loading or if I quickly hit another chromium browser tab, the page then completes the load. I've looked in the chrome://flags and cannot find out a solution. I've read that some JavaScript legacy functions could be the issue but after disabling them in the chrome/Flags/ experiments, nothing seems to have changed. I running a AMD Desktop with 16gb and SSD. I cannot see anything in the logs.

Anybody got any clues to what are the issues?

Amended: I changed some Render options in the Chromium Flags, please refer to the second screenshot whereby I set the said Render to either 'enable' or 'default', this appears to have halted the issue. Maybe it's now a hardware problem (ie gfx card), I'll leave this open for few hours/days to see if it stays fixed and then I'll close it and feedback. I don't think is was a URL browsing issue as previously suggested.

[image]

Comment: Can you press F12, to bring up the dev tools, switch to the network pane and try to load a new page with the dev tools open? Post a screenshot of the network pane. This will show us what Chromium spends time on, roughly speaking.

Comment: Sure done that. Use DevTools for WebDev. Maybe it's just seasonal traffic?

Comment: Pinpointing to: Enable Render Level Data Use Optimization
Allow Render Level Data Use Optimization – Mac, Windows, Linux,....... I again disabled the option as some images were not showing. The images then were doing so and the previous issue had not returned. Possibly this has some influence. BTw, I'm using Ubuntu default graphics open source driver on an Nvidia  GT218 [GeForce 210] card if that is culpable.